# textArea.append () formatting to align 3 Strings (1 parsed Int) and a Double with their headers in a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, append, jtextarea

this is a  1st year 1st term Java Fund assignment, so `JTextArea` is the requirement (no Tables).

The essence of the problem is how do I set a uniform amount of spacing for some lines (up to 10) after the first string of each line which is a full name from user input.

From the screen shot you can see there is a method display per customer as they are input and then a `displayAll()` method which is producing the GUI output.

I've been playing with variations on the `textArea.setText` code, which is in a called to method and runs like this:

```
textArea.setText(String.format("%-23s%-25s%-28s%-26s\n", "Customer name", "License number", "Days hired", "Rental"));
textArea.append("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
```

Happy days for that part, but along comes Super Superman or Fancy Fancypants Jnr, a long name and the output is not aligned.

I have tried to set the font suggestions I have found, but this causes something crazy to happen to the `JTextArea` and parts are cut off... I think because of the appended "----" dashes under the heading.

It seems to be something obvious to do with how much space I allow after the first string, and then maybe I should decreases the spaces after the remaining strings?

I get it that obviously a display of 7 for days and $134.00 will likely need more space after the last string formatted... or is it less space.  If you can't tell, it's a minor thing but it's frustrating :)

The example output from our specification seems to be much more evenly aligned than I can manage so far, so any ideas on nailing this down would be much appreciated.

GUI Output and code screenshot
[Specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMADz.png)

Comment: Why not using TAB's?

Comment: yeah i have a text book that says \t for tabs and some escape sequences don't work in GUI environment.  And I am sure some of my classmates tried and it doesn't help.  But I will give it a go if it should work...

Comment: is their a tab method that isn't escape sequence based?

Comment: You need to use a monospaced font if you are trying to align characters in a specific column.